# Intake torque specs for 95 Chevrolet S10?

Tags: engine, chevrolet, s10, torque-specification

What are the torque specs for a 95 Chevrolet S10 4.3 vortec with intake number 10172785?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the exact vehicle. The VIN will either have a W or a Z (I don't know which position this will be in, but I'm assuming it will be self evident). These values hold true for either the 94 or 95 S10 with the 4.3L Vortec engine. Here is the torque sequence for the intake:

[image]

The amount of torque, depending on the VIN are as follows:

VIN Z:

- All except bolt A: 35 lb-ft
- Bolt A: 41 lb-ft

VIN W:

- Lower: 35 lb-ft
- Upper: 10 lb-ft

**NOTE:** This information is pulled from a Haynes manual, including the image.

Comment: For "VIN W", do "upper" and "lower" refer to their orientation in the picture provided?

Comment: @FreeMan - No, the image provided is for VIN Z.